# Is there any point in going to university?

Tags: the-sims-3, sims-3-ambitions

I will have my sim join the ghosthunter profession.

From what I read graduating from university seems to do good only for rabbithole jobs.

Is there any point in going to university?

Comment: Any of the ones which require logic, as logic is needed for Ghosthunting

Comment: @AliceRees ...ironically.

Comment: Can you define "any of the ones which requires logic"? Are you talking about university majors?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I don't know all the details, or I would have posted them in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Sim to take on a profession where you have open hours (firefighter, writer, painter, angler, etc.), then there isn't much benefit to going to university aside from the chance to boost your skills.

That isn't to say that there aren't any benefits to pursuing a career after going to university. This is mainly meant for anyone looking to join the standard professions, and getting good grades in college will allow your Sim to start out on a higher career level when first applying to that job. If you finish your college career with a perfect GPA, your Sim will start out at level 4 of their chosen career with a higher daily salary than you would get by reaching level 4 in that career normally.

Additionally, if you complete college after reaching the maximum level of influence with any of the social groups (Jocks, Nerds, or Rebels), you get an offer for an exclusive job not available anywhere else in the game - Jocks can become Sports Agents, Nerds can become Video Game Developers, and Rebels can become Art Critics.

Answer (score 3):

Completing a Degree with A level gives you an extra trait slot (for a total of 7 if you have the one from social group level as well). That by itself is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get certain job boosts based on your major, but the only advantage to university compared to an "honorary degree" is the experience. If you don't want to spend a fair amount of time playing one sim and working on their degree/social life, University is not for you.